# In ES6, does the for loop init expression get redeclared when using let?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

I'm trying to clarify the meaning behind this statement from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

> The example above works as intended because the five instances of the
>   (anonymous) inner function refer to five different instances of the
>   variable i.

Say the for loop init expression uses the `let` keyword. Does the expression get redeclared on each iteration (i.e., there is a new scope)? For example,

```
var func;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (i == 1) {
    func = () => i
  }
  if (i == 4) {
    i = 100
  }
}
console.log(func()) // output is 1
```

The output of `func()` is `1` even though `i == 4` by the end of the for loop. This seems to indicate that `i` in `func` comes from a scope where `i == 1`, even though `i` gets set to `100` on the last iteration.

Compare that to the following where `i` gets declared outside of the for loop block.

```
if (true) {
  var func;
  let i = 0
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
      func = () => i
    }
    if (i == 4) {
      i = 999
    }
  }
}
console.log(func()) // output is 999
```

In this case, it seems that there is a single instance of `i` which gets updated (but not redeclared) on the last iteration.

So, does using `let` cause the for loop to create a new block scope with a new declaration of the init variable for each iteration?

Comment: Variables declared with `let` are block scoped. By declaring `i` as part of the for loop, it becomes scoped to that loop block. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Yes, it is scoped per iteration. (Except in IE, which didn't implement it properly for declarations within the `for`'s parentheses, though it did implement it for declarations within the loop body.)

Comment: I believe `let` is limited to the scope of the loop, so there is a new declaration on each iteration **but** uses the previous value as reference like a closure does.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared by `let` are scoped in their closest block.

> http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_core-features.html#sec_from-var-to-const
>
> In ES6, you can additionally declare variables via let and const. Such variables are block-scoped, their scopes are the innermost enclosing blocks. let is roughly a block-scoped version of var.

Which means your code should be equivalent with this:

```
var func;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function (j) {
    if (j == 1) {
      func = () => j
    }
    if (j == 4) {
      j = 100
    }
  })(i);
}
console.log(func()) // output is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Section [13.7.4.9 of the ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-createperiterationenvironment) seems to indicate that what zer00ne mentioned is true:

- there is a new environment created for each iteration of the loop,
- and a new binding of `i` created in that environment,
- and its value is set to the value of the binding from the previous
  iteration (rather than being re-initialized)

> iii Let lastValue be lastIterationEnv.GetBindingValue(bn, true).
>
> v. Perform thisIterationEnv.InitializeBinding(bn, lastValue).

A function declared inside a loop will form a closure over the binding specific to the iteration - so effectively you'll get a different closure for each iteration of the loop.